# What causes Getting a neither bindingresult nor plain target object error in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `<form:options>` in my jsp for which I have defined the path attribute. It looks like this

```
<form:select id="drpDwn" path="usrNm" onchange="getUserNames()">
```

My Controller method signature looks like this, I am just calling my service method to populate the user names

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usrForm", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
  public @ResponseBody JSONArray getUserNames(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, OutputStream opStream){
           return usrService.getUserNames(userId, opStream);
}
```

When I am submitting the page I am getting the error

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'usrNm' available as request attribute
```

I looked up the forum and found that I have to define the Model Attribute , but I have not understood the root cause of this issue.

Can anybody please list it down , and explain that what is it exactly that Spring is looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the form expects a bean called `usrNm`. Whichever controller directs to the page with the form  should set that bean.

The controller you show is for processing the form (I assume), however it is the code that returns the view with the form on that is causing the error.

Comment: so this means that I have to create a bean named `usrNm` , and return a `new ModelandView` with the `usrNm` set in it

Comment: yes, although to get the error you must already have half that - it is being forwarded to the correct page at least.

Comment: NimChimpsky  
got it right this time. Thanks for the hint. 
As you have pointed out the code that returns the view was causing the error. Modified it to include the model attribute for `usrNm` and things worked. :)